# MFSideMenu how to load in another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfslidemenu

My App is based in a `LoginView` and `SecondView`. I will show SecondView after login.

I don't want to make `MFSideMenu` on `LoginView`. I would like to use `MFSideMenu` just in the `SecondView`. I am trying to do it in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


 UIViewController *baseViewApp = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MFSideMenuContainerViewController"];

 MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)baseViewApp.view.window.rootViewController;

 //MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

 UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];

 UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];
 UIViewController *rightSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightSideMenuViewController"];


 [container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
 [container setRightMenuViewController:rightSideMenuViewController];
 [container setCenterViewController:navigationController];

return YES;
}
```

In the image above I am showing my StoryBoard Properties from my `SideMenuContainerView` (Where I want to load the `MFSideMenu`):

http://santoro.co/ios_deve.png

The `MFSideMenu` is working when I start Build my app with the initial `ViewController`.

My `SecondView` and with this line:

```
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

But when I try this:

```
UIViewController *baseViewApp = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MFSideMenuContainerViewController"];

 MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)baseViewApp.view.window.rootViewController;
```

The `MFSideMenu` does not work.

Comment: Code that is written in appDelegate, you have to write that code in click event of login button.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to access it form the app delegate you will find the code here.  The trick is trying to get the UINavigationController. You can see here I find it via the window.

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    HomeViewController * homeVC = [storyboard 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:homeVC];
    UINavigationController * navigationController = (UINavigationController* )container.centerViewController;
    navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

Comment: Where should I write above code? because I want to implement same kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Pull on a new UIViewController that will act as the login view controller onto the MainStoryboard. In the attribute inspector change the identifier to LoginViewController (or something appropriate)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];

      UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
      UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
      [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

      [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

and after successful login just dismiss LoginViewController

Comment: Can`t i just doing it ???
`
UIViewController *baseViewApp = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MFSideMenuContainerViewController"];

 MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)baseViewApp.view.window.rootViewController;
``

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the Lib to [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels).

Comment: To say True... the https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController is much better !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 VideosViewController *videosViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideosViewController"];

            UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
            NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:videosViewController];
            navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
    //VKJ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:YourViewController];

MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.view.window.rootViewController;
[container setCenterViewController:nav];
```

Answer (score 0):

there should not be any links(segues) or connections to main and side view controllers(from main and side can be set), set identifiers else storyboard ID (`MainMenuViewController` ---> `mainVC`, `SideMenuViewController` ---> `sideVC`), `import MainMenuViewController, SideMenuViewController, MFSideMenu` on `loginview`, now calling below will move view:

```
MainMenuViewController *mainMenuVC = [self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: 
@"mainVC"];

SideMenuViewController *sideVC = [self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
@"sideVC"];

        MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                        containerWithCenterViewController:mainMenuVC
                                                        leftMenuViewController:sideVC
                                                        rightMenuViewController:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:container animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two methods for login and sidemenu creatation
2. In Appdeleagate.h Add this

   - (void)createLoginPage;
   - (void)createSidemenuPage;
3. In Appdelegate.m implement the defination of the above methods.
   Example:-
4. Create storybard for sidemenu with the name of SideMenuStoryBoardName and drag a view controller in that add table view this is for sidemenu.
5. Create storybard for home with the name of CenterStoryboardName and drag a view controller and set the identifier for that view controller.
6. Call the createSidemenu method after login success using appdelegate object.

Code:

```
(void)createLoginPage
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    UIStoryboard *loginStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:LoginStoryBoardName bundle:nil];
    SigninViewController *signVC = [loginStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:SigninViewControllerIdentifier];
    UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:signVC];
    nav.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

(void)createSidemenuPage
{
    //-- Left ViewController
    UIStoryboard *sideMenuSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:SideMenuStoryBoardName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    SideMenu *sideMenuVC = [sideMenuSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:SideMenuIdentifier];
    //-- Center ViewController
    UIStoryboard *centerVC = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:CenterStoryboardName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:centerVC];
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container  =[MFSideMenuContainerViewController containerWithCenterViewController:navigationController leftMenuViewController:sideMenuVC rightMenuViewController:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = container;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```